# Use asyncio methods on tornado's ioloop (such as create_future)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio, ioloop

I am aware that since 5.0 tornado's ioloop is handled by asyncio and in fact the loop I get using `tornado.ioloop.IOloop.current()` **is** an asyncio loop by default. My question is how do I access the asyncio loop itself in a proper way. For example I would like to use the `loop.create_future()` method on the asyncio loop, but tornado wraps the loop and it doesn't have this method on it.

Currently what I do is when I need asyncio methods I just call `asyncio.get_event_loop()` (because the documentation states that the two loops are indeed identical). I am not sure this is the correct way of doing this since now I have different references to the same ioloop with different interfaces and I use the one that is needed. This is kind of messy and confusing.

Is there a better way? Can I tell tornado to give me the asyncio loop without wrapping it? Or can I access these methods somehow using the `IOloop` that tornado creates?

EDIT:

https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#module-tornado.ioloop Here it states the following:

> Applications can use either the IOLoop interface or the underlying asyncio event loop directly

I am interested in the latter, yet I can’t find instructions on how to access it directly.

Comment: Have you tried asyncio's top-level functions, such as ``asyncio.ensure_future``? The event loop is generally published for its payloads.

Comment: In the specific use case I mentioned (but I'd rather ask this generally) I had to create a asyncio.Future object and asyncio's documentation clearly states that to do that properly you need to call `create_future()` on the loop. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_future

Am I missing something, is there a top level method for everything to be used in tornado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio.get_event_loop()` is the recommended method; no need to use the (undocumented) `asyncio_loop` attribute. This is how all non-tornado-specific asyncio code gets the event loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I already use tornado's ioloop's for calling add_callback and such things, is it considered a good practice to get the reference to the asyncio_loop via `asyncio.get_event_loop()` if I want to use methods that don't exists on tornado's ioloop, such as `create_future`? Or should I just use asyncio everywhere?

Comment: I'd say it's a good practice to avoid mixing the two event loops in the same block of code, if possible. If you've already got an asyncio loop for `create_future`, use its `call_soon` instead of `add_callback`. But if you do need unique features of both loops, just use `IOLoop.current()` and `asyncio.get_event_loop()`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way. So the ioloop that tornado creates will be of type `AsyncIOMainLoop`. I went to the source code and its base class is `BaseAsyncIOLoop` in that class there is a property called `asyncio_loop`

With that I was finally able to use asyncio loop. (`ioloop.IOLoop.current().asyncio_loop`)